# Question about Cisco WIC-2T

Tags: networking, cisco

I am using some (what I thought was) wic-2t cards in 1721s that I ordered from Ebay.  I was trying to set the clock rate on one of the interfaces and received an error.  The card in slot0 works fine, but the card in slot1 appears to not be a wic-2t, but a wic-2a/s instead.  The cards look identical, both  cards are labeled wic-2t.  I tried the card in mutltiple routers, and in both slots of each router to no avail.  Did I get ripped off or is this actually a wic-2t card?

```
~
1000000
1300000
1600000
2000000
2600000
3200000
4000000
5300000
8000000
(config-if)#clock rate 2600000
%Error: Unsupported clock rate for this interface

#sho diag
Slot 0:

    C1721 1FE Mainboard Port adapter, 5 ports
    Port adapter is analyzed
    Port adapter insertion time unknown
    EEPROM contents at hardware discovery:
    Hardware Revision        : 5.0
    PCB Serial Number        : FOC09172BVV
    Part Number              : 73-7546-05
    Board Revision           : A0
    Fab Version              : 04
    Product (FRU) Number     : CISCO1721
    EEPROM format version 4
    EEPROM contents (hex):
      0x00: 04 FF 40 03 5A 41 05 00 C1 8B 46 4F 43 30 39 31
      0x10: 37 32 42 56 56 82 49 1D 7A 05 42 41 30 02 04 FF
      0x20: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
      0x30: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
      0x40: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
      0x50: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
      0x60: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
      0x70: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF


    WIC/VIC Slot 0:
    Serial 2T (12in1)
    Hardware revision 1.0   Board revision D0
    Serial number     0024928405    Part number    800-03181-01
    FRU Part Number   WIC-2T=


    Test history      0x00          RMA number     00-00-00
    Connector type    PCI
    EEPROM format version 1
    EEPROM contents (hex):
    0x20:   01 12 01 00 01 7C 60 95 50 0C 6D 01 00 00 00 00
    0x30:   68 00 00 00 01 01 15 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF


    WIC/VIC Slot 1:
    Serial 2A/S (12in1)
    Hardware revision 1.0   Board revision C0
    Serial number     0023246138    Part number    800-03182-01
    FRU Part Number   WIC-2A/S=


    Test history      0x00          RMA number     00-00-00
    Connector type    PCI
    EEPROM format version 1
    EEPROM contents (hex):
    0x20:   01 13 01 00 01 62 B5 3A 50 0C 6E 01 00 00 00 00
    0x30:   60 00 00 00 00 07 08 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [WIC-2A/S](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/modules/ps3129/products_tech_note09186a00800b1502.shtml) and [WIC-2T](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/routers/ps274/products_tech_note09186a00800b0858.shtml) look *very* similar externally. I'd take what the firmware is reporting to be true. If the card that is detecting as a WIC-2A/S is physically labeled WIC-2T then I'd be very, very suspicious of the WIC being genuine.

Comment: I guess I have to accept that it's not a real WIC-2T.  It is physically labeled WIC-2T, and looks perfect, but guess I got ripped off...

Comment: There have been a lot of counterfeit Cisco WICs dumped into the market in the last few years. Several models have been knocked-off, including the WIC-2T.